# How to access testcase property from TestSuite setup script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am planning to read data from excel and set them as Testcase level properties.

So I am trying to set data from the setup script of testsuite,
something like

```
log.info testSuite.testCase.getTestCaseByName('OW_Y_D_DE_UMNR').getName()
```

But I am getting an error stating

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testCase for class: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite Possible solutions: testCases

Comment: Did you read the error? _"Possible solutions: testCases"_ Have you tried `testSuite.testCases.getTestCaseByName('OW_Y_D_DE_UMNR').getName()`?  ie:  `testCases`, not `testCase`

Comment: Yes I did try them, dint work out. Instead got this error ***groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.getTestCaseByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [OW_Y_D_DE_UMNR]***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, looked at [the documentation for testSuite](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlTestSuite.html#getTestCaseByName(java.lang.String)) and I think you just need:

```
testSuite.getTestCaseByName('OW_Y_D_DE_UMNR').getN‌​ame()
```